# I want to add day name in calendar

Tags: php

I want to add $day_of_week with the $day_num , but i'm getting some weird combination ( 1 Tue   2 Tuf   3 Tug   4 Tuh   5 Tui 6 Tuj     7 Tuk   8 Tul   9 Tum   10 Tun  11 Tuo  12 Tup)

the calendar does not display  1 Tue    2 Tuf   3 Tug  etc. anymore I took that out.

I want the calendar to look like this (1 Mon 2 Tue  3 Wed  4 Thu  5 Fri  6 Sat   7 Sun)

this is the code part where it is causing the problem

```
//count up the days, untill we've done all of them in the month
 while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month )
 { 
 echo "<td> $day_num $day_of_week </td>"; 
 $day_num++; 
 $day_count++;
$day_of_week++;
 //Make sure we start a new row every week
 if ($day_count > 7)
 {
 echo "</tr><tr>";
 $day_count = 1;
 }
 }
```

this is the complete code, without the modifications above

```
<?php 
 //This gets today's date 
 $date =time () ; 
 //This puts the day, month, and year in seperate variables 
 $day = date('d', $date) ; 
 $month = date('m', $date) ; 
 $year = date('Y', $date) ;
 //Here we generate the first day of the month 
 $first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year) ; 
 //This gets us the month name 
 $title = date('F', $first_day) ;
 //Here we find out what day of the week the first day of the month falls on 
 $day_of_week = date('D', $first_day) ; 
 //Once we know what day of the week it falls on, we know how many blank days occure before it. If the first day of the week is a Sunday then it would be zero
 switch($day_of_week){ 
 case "Sun": $blank = 0; break; 
 case "Mon": $blank = 1; break; 
 case "Tue": $blank = 2; break; 
 case "Wed": $blank = 3; break; 
 case "Thu": $blank = 4; break; 
 case "Fri": $blank = 5; break; 
 case "Sat": $blank = 6; break; 
 }
 //We then determine how many days are in the current month
 $days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year) ; 
 //Here we start building the table heads 
 echo "<table border=1 width=294>";
 echo "<tr><th colspan=7> $title $year </th></tr>";
 echo "<tr><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>M</td><td 
width=42>T</td><td width=42>W</td><td width=42>T</td><td 
width=42>F</td><td width=42>S</td></tr>";
 //This counts the days in the week, up to 7
 $day_count = 1;
 echo "<tr>";
 //first we take care of those blank days
 while ( $blank > 0 ) 
 { 
 echo "<td></td>"; 
 $blank = $blank-1; 
 $day_count++;
 } 
 //sets the first day of the month to 1 
 $day_num = 1;

 //count up the days, untill we've done all of them in the month
 while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month  ) 
 { 
 echo "<td> $day_num </td>"; 
 $day_num++; 
 $day_count++;

 //Make sure we start a new row every week
 if ($day_count > 7)
 {
 echo "</tr><tr>";
 $day_count = 1;
 }
 } 
 //Finaly we finish out the table with some blank details if needed
 while ( $day_count >1 && $day_count <=7 ) 
 { 
 echo "<td> </td>"; 
 $day_count++; 
 } 

 echo "</tr></table>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Somewhere, somehow, you're doing `$var = 'Tue'`, then `$var++`. Can't see how/where this is happening in your code, but that's why you have `Tue`, `Tuf`, `Tug`, etc... notice e->f->g.... you're incrementing a string.

Comment: hi marc the code only displays the number at the moment, I took out the part where it displays (tue, tuf, tug, etc.)

Comment: this is where it display the number  echo "<td> $day_num </td>";

Comment: You have to convert this value `$day_of_week` to a day using an `array` of populated values with numeric keys  associated with the text value like: `$daysInWeek[1] = 'mon'; $daysInWeek[2] = 'tue';` etc... then `echo $daysInWeek[$day_of_week];`

Comment: @rasclatt no I haven't. How would that look like?

Comment: I just need to add <?php  date('D') ; ?>  to every single day on the calendar

Comment: Oh I thought you were doing a 1-7 day header row but I see what you are doing. Yeah you need a date() usage there.

Comment: I think you need to do an `mktime()` on that variable as well, passing the month, day, and year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted, this part needs to have an `mtkime()` calculation:

```
 //count up the days, until we've done all of them in the month
 while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month  ) { 
     echo "<td> $day_num ".date("D",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day_num,$year))."</td>"; 
     $day_num++; 
     $day_count++;

     //Make sure we start a new row every week
     if ($day_count > 7) {
         echo "</tr><tr>";
         $day_count = 1;
     }
 }
```